# Javascript - call a function when you finish typing

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an input in wich the user is going to type some text. When he finish typing I want to call a function automatically.

This is what I have done till now:

```
<input type="text" oninput="change();"/>

<script>
function changing(){
    alert('You stoped typing!');
}
function change(){
    clearTimeout(changing);
    setTimeout(changing, 2000);
}
</script>
```

What I am expecting :

When you type, `change` is called. It cancels the last `changing` that was supposed to run in 2 seconds and run a new `changing` within 2 seconds.

What actually happens :

When you type, `change` is called. It doesn't cancel the last `changing` that was supposed to run in 2 seconds but still run a new `changing` within 2 seconds. As you type, the first alert window will appear 2 seccond after you start typing and keep showing again and again one after another.

Is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimeout()` returns a timer ID.  It is that timer ID that you must pass to `clearTimeout()` for it to work properly (you are passing the callback function to `clearTimeout()` and that is not how it works).

So, you need to store the return value from `setTimeout()` into a variable in a lasting scope that you can then later pass to `clearTimeout()` like this:

```
<input type="text" oninput="change();"/>

<script>
function changing(){
    alert('You stoped typing!');
}
var timer;
function change(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(changing, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout()` function returns a value that must be used later with `clearTimeout()` if you need to cancel it.

```
var timer;
function changing(){
    alert('You stoped typing!');
}
function change(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(changing, 2000);
}
```